# gls Regression with variable transform

Tags: regression, predictive-models, interaction, fitting, generalized-least-squares

I'm learning about logistics regression and gls regression. And I came across an interesting finding. I have 2 predictor variables ($x_1$ and $x_2$) and if I plot the response variable with $x_2$, there is a nice convex curve in the data. I decided to transform $x_2$ with ${x_2}^2$ (x2a) and add it to the data. So my new model will have 3 predictor variables.

I used 2 methods to build regression model:

```
gls(y~ x1 + x2 + x2a, data=sample)
gls(y~ x1 * x2 * x2a, data=sample)
```

The second model with interaction among the 3 predictors gives me the lowest mean square errors when vetted against the same dataset. What are some ways to explain this? Does interaction between predictors tend to produce a better result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, when you use `x1 * x2` in the formula, you are telling the regression to include these variables and the interactions between them. So your second model has the first model *and* the interaction term. If you want just the interaction term in the second model, you should do `x1:x2` instead.

As you have it now, since the second model includes the first model, it has a lower MSE.

Comment: Thanks. Also I found if the more predictors I add, the better the model becomes based on the same data used to produce the model. When I plot the predictions, it's like a zigzag line. Adj r square becomes very close to 1 and MSE is almost 0. Would this be overfitting?